# Comparing two variables in while loop BASH

Tags: bash

I am trying to compare two variable in bash in nested `while` loops and I am having issues with:

> [: 1, : integer expression expected.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="10",b="5"
i="1", j="1"
while [ $i -ne $a ]
do
        while [ $j -ne $b ]
        do
                echo"In Child Loop $j Times"
                ((j++))
        done
        j="1"
        echo"In Parent Loop $i Times"
        ((i++))
done
```

Comment: separate your variables with a semicolon instead of a comma, i.e., a="10";b="5"

Comment: I recommend `-lt` over `-ne` in this case.   Or replace both `[ ... ]` tests with `(( ... <  ... ))`.   The script already does not conform to POSIX because of the `((i++))`.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful? If so, accept it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **2** primary issues. **(1)** you forgot to leave a space between `echo` and the start of the string, and **(2)** as pointed out, a comma is **not** a valid `end of line` specifier in bash. Bash uses a `semi-colon` as the `end of line` specifier. Meaning if you want to put 2 assignments on the same line, you must put a `;` between them, not a `,`. With the changes your code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="10"
b="5"
i="1"
j="1"

while [ $i -ne $a ]
do
    while [ $j -ne $b ]
    do
        echo "In Child Loop $j Times"
        ((j++))
    done
    j="1"
    echo "In Parent Loop $i Times"
    ((i++))
done
```

**output:**

```
$ bash nestedtest.sh
In Child Loop 1 Times
In Child Loop 2 Times
In Child Loop 3 Times
In Child Loop 4 Times
In Parent Loop 1 Times
In Child Loop 1 Times
In Child Loop 2 Times
In Child Loop 3 Times
In Child Loop 4 Times
In Parent Loop 2 Times
In Child Loop 1 Times
In Child Loop 2 Times
In Child Loop 3 Times
In Child Loop 4 Times
In Parent Loop 3 Times
In Child Loop 1 Times
In Child Loop 2 Times
In Child Loop 3 Times
In Child Loop 4 Times
In Parent Loop 4 Times
(snip)
```

Additionally, since bash does not have `typed variables`, there can be ambiguity whether a variable should be treated as a number or as a string. Type is determined by context. However, you can let bash know how you intend to use a variable if you `declare` the variable before its first use. E.g.:

```
declare -i a="10" b="5" i="1" j="1"
```

**NOTE:** here you **can** place more than one declaration on a single line simply separate by a space.

Additionally, if you receive an `"[: 1, : integer expression expected"` error. that is usually due to one of two reasons. **(1)** the variable is not defined yet, or **(2)** it doesn't contain a number. The way you avoid that is to **always make sure you initialize your variables** before you test them. (you did here, you just had the `comma` problem).

Lastly, while not required on numeric values, it is a good idea to `double-quote` your variables. This will save you many many headaches along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do two string assignments separates with commas, since "," is added to the value of first variable. For example:

```
a="10", b="5"
echo $a
> 10,
```

Instead, do each assignment on its own line:

```
a="10"
b="5"
i="1"
j="1"
```

Alternatively, you can remove commas in your initialization lines:

```
a=10 b=5
i=1 j=1
```

Comment: this is "shell" programming

Answer (score 1):

You *can* combine multiple assignments, separated by whitespace only.
Just replace the commas with spaces:

```
a="10" b="5"
i="1" j="1"
```

Or even:

```
a="10" b="5" i="1" j="1"
```

You can also remove quotes and reduce clutter:

```
a=10 b=5 i=1 j=1
```

But caution is advised here.  Keep things readable.

---

The shell has a rule for dealing with assignments prefixing commands.
For an *external* command, that command will run with the assigned variables *in* its own *environment*.

For an *internal* command, the assignment(s) will be permanent for the current process,
so the variables and their values will persist after the command completes.